# Using firebase auth on backend instead of front

Tags: javascript, firebase

From the firebase docs, there seems to be heavy emphasis on using the firebase adapter i.e. `firebase.auth()` on the front end. It seems that if it's included in your front end, firebase will handle persistence automatically, amongst other things.

With my Node.js backend, how should I communicate the current user information from my front end (react native), to my Node backend (which will call firebase)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your back end, you need to use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup). For communication, it depends what you are doing. For example, lets say that you're trying to do login. The user will enter their credentials (Username and password) using you front end, and then you can use

> firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credentials)

to get their authentication token. This token can then be pass to your back end as a header to authenticate the user.